# Hiding source of particle instancing

Tags: particles

I have emitted instanced object as particle. I can hide emitter with Emitter checkbox but how can I hide source object? It is still visible in scene, but I want only instance. If I hide source object, also emitted object dissappear.

Comment: are you using the Particle instance modifier? because it is supposed to hide the source object automatically

Comment: No I didnt know this modifier :) It is working good! :) Why there is two same things in Blender?

Comment: do add this as an answer or it is done?

Comment: Be careful using the particle instance modifier, as it creates a *copy* of the mesh for each particle (very memory hungry). Regular particles use instances, referencing the same mesh data for every particle. @Chebhou Feel free to add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is by putting all the source objects on a separate layer (<kbd>M</kbd>).

Comment: Thanks for tip! And what if my scene with particles is grouped and linked in another scene? I need use same particles in many scenes. If I used proxy to source object it is duplicated, but still remain in scene.

Answer (score 6):

Set the object material like this if you want the emitter linked:

[image]

This will render them with material for particles and transparent for the original object.

*I wish just unlinking the object from the scene would work as it works with bone shapes so it doesn't pollute the scene and also works with linking. But it doesn't :/*