# how to hide mesh but keep hair particles

Tags: mesh, particles

I'm using hair on my mesh but when I comb the mesh the hair goes through it. I don't want the mesh anyways so instead of figuring out how to stop the hair from going through the mesh I'm trying to figure out how make the mesh invisible but not the hair. When I use a transparency node it effects hair and mesh

I added the particle instance modifier like it says in this question [Hiding source of particle instancing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26014/hiding-source-of-particle-instancing) but it didn't hide the mesh.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Go to particle settings and disable emiter

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PropertiesEditor-->Particles-->Render-->Emitter.

this will hide the mesh in render view
[image]

Comment: but thats not talking about hair

Comment: oh nevermind thankyou. i had it enabled instead of disbled

Comment: it wont let me like your post cuz i dont have enough reputation sorry

Comment: no problem, I learned it from the blender reference manual https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/particles/visualization.html

Comment: And what about Blender 2.8 ?  It is not working the same way...

Answer (score 9):

## Blender 2.8+

*Object Properties* > *Instancing* > *Display Instancer/Render Instancer*

In Blender 2.8, this is done by disabling *Display Instancer* (for viewport) and *Render Instancer* (for render) in the *Instancing* panel of *Object Properties*.

[image: Object Properties > Instancing > Display Instancer/Render Instancer]