# Eevee & particles: hide mesh emitter at render

Tags: particles, eevee-render-engine

It was simple to hide the object that emits particles in Cycles [by unchecking 
emitter](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/55715/14306) in PropertiesEditor-->Particles-->Render.

But there is no such option with Eevee.
How could I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your needs, deselect "Display duplicator" and/or "Render duplicator" in the Object properties panel.

This works in Blender 2.8 regardless of the rendering engine (it works with Cycles too). It applies to every situation in which an object is used to create instances of other objects.

[image]

Note that unchecking "Display Duplicator" will prevent you from selecting the object with right-click in the Viewport: you'll still be able to select it from the Outliner.

(As of today, the viewport doesn't update correctly once you uncheck the boxes, but if you advance one frame in the timeline it should refresh)

Comment: now duplication is called "instancing".